# Facebook comments generating javascript error

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-comments

I'm having a javascript error in every browsers in local AND online when using *Facebook comments*. 
Trying to retreive 0 or multiple comments doesn't seems to change anything.
Anyone have an idea?
**Error message**

Message : 'this._count.value.0' is Null or not an Object.
All.js, Line: 48, Code: 0
URI : http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1

**Code in the page**

```
<fb:comments-count href="<%= WebTools.Permalink %>"></fb:comments-count>
<fb:comments href="<%= WebTools.Permalink %>" num_posts="2" width="839"></fb:comments>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found out that **this is an issue on Facebook’s end**.
The same code work in dev and prod, but not in local or staging...

**For more informations**
There is a site explaining it in details: 
 http://www.codepreneur.com/2011/07/facebook-like-button-not-working-or-resets-itself/

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully diagnosed and resolved this issue.

Here was my code that was asynchronously loading the Facebook JavaScript SDK:

```
(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Here was my code that was initializing it:

```
FB.init({
    appId: {APP_ID},
    status: true,
    cookie: true,
    xfbml: true,
    oauth: true
});
```

Note that I've actually requested XFBML parsing twice: once when loading the JavaScript SDK (`#xfbml=1`), and once when initializing it (`xfbml: true`).

This causes the error that prevents `comment-count` tags from rendering.

The resolution is to eliminate one of those two declarations; I would suggest deleting `#xfbml=1` from the end of the JavaScript SDK URL, as requesting XFBML parsing at load time [seems to be deprecated](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/).

My loader now looks like this:

```
(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

And everything works perfectly.

### Synchronous loading

If you load the JavaScript SDK synchronously, change this:

```
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
```

To this:

```
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```